# add options by javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function.
This function is supposed to populate a html select-box by adding options.

```
Argument passed is, for example, [['val1','txt1'],['val2','txt2']]
```

I expected that it would generate the html as under:

```
<select id='element_id'>
    <option value='val1'>txt1</option>
    <option value='val2'>txt2</option>
</select>

<script>
function popu_select(x) {
    for (i in x) {
      $('#element_id').append($(document.createElement("option")).attr("value", "i[0]").text("i[1]"));
              }
</script>
```

But it is not populating the select-box.
What I may be doing wrong here?

Regards,
Vineet

Comment: It's worth noting that iterating through an array with "for ... in" is considered bad practice. Instead, it's better to use a numeric index in a plain "for" loop.

Comment: @Pointy, You are right. I will make use of a numeric index in a plain "for" loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code here so that it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/52nRL/

using the jQuery `$.each` function.

Answer (score 4):

At least, you need to get the item of the array (i is only the index), and remove quotes when accessing the variables. Try this:

```
  function popu_select(x) {
    for (i in x) {
      var item = x[i]
      $('#element_id').append($(document.createElement("option")).attr("value", item[0]).text(item[1]));
    }
```

Comment: Should also be noted that appending each time through the loop will be a performance hit when your list gets longer. I recommend storing your options in a variable and appending once the loop is complete.

Comment: `for..in` for arrays kills more kittens than `eval` :-(

Comment: Thanks to all. I will try each method suggested here & adopt the best suited to my purpose. If stuck-up, will pot the problem here again.

Comment: @idrumgood, sometimes I do have lists as long as thousands of items.   But I did not understand what you suggest by "I recommend storing your options in a variable and appending once the loop is complete". Bcoz the options are there in a variable itself.   What is meant by "appending once the loop is complete".   Can you pl. explaint in a bit detail? Thanks.

Comment: @Vineet you're creating a `<select>` element with **thousands** of `<option>` elements inside? Won't that be somewhat difficult to use (to say the least)?

Comment: I plan to use incremental search. Looking for how to do that. Can you pl. help?

Comment: What I mean by the above comment is: Can I achieve incremental searching in a select box? Maybe by using a JQuery plugin? Or plain js? any pointer on the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use JSON to pass arguments in:

```
var args = [{value:1, text:'one'}, {value:2, text:'two'}];

$.each(para, function(i, option){ 
  $('#element_id').append("<option value='" + option.value + "'>" + option.text + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this method suggested here & if stuck-up, will pot the problem here again.

Answer (score 1):

Not jQuery, but this [example](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/) does exactly what you want.  It even includes an example for adding options from an array like you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this method suggested here & if stuck-up, will pot the problem here again.